# Cannot use all arguments of $@ with sh -c

Tags: bash, command-line-arguments

In a script, I have a `sh -c` command that involves `$@` but it seems that only the first item of `$@` is taken into account :

```
$ set -- --no-resume-playback https://www.facebook.com/TBN/videos/1580372468665943/
$ echo "$@"
--no-resume-playback https://www.facebook.com/TBN/videos/1580372468665943/
$ sh -c "echo $@"
--no-resume-playback
$ sh -c "echo ${@[*]}"
bash: echo ${@[*]}: bad substitution
```

EDIT 1 : If I copy `$@` array into a variable, it works :

```
$ args=("$@")
$ sh -c "echo ${args[*]}"
--no-resume-playback https://www.facebook.com/TBN/videos/1580372468665943/
```

How can I use all arguments of `$@` in a `sh -c` call ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`$@` expands as separate words, even when it's in double quotes and looks like one word. The command you wrote expands to:

```
sh -c "echo --no-resume-playback" https://www.facebook.com/TBN/videos/1580372468665943/
```

The command run is `echo --no-resume-playback` with `$0` set to the Facebook URL. `echo --no-resume-playback` doesn't use `$0`, so it's effectively discarded.

You have the right idea with `${@[*]}`. As it happens, `$@` is a special case  with unique syntax: you want `$*`, which expands to a single word.

```
sh -c "echo $*"
```

This is a little dangerous since any arguments with wildcards like `*` could get expanded. If you want to be safe you'd need this more complicated version:

```
sh -c 'echo "$@"' sh "$@"
```

This forwards `"$@"` as arguments to the `-c` command so that we can in turn use `"$@"` inside. Note that I've now switched to single quotes: we want the subshell to expand `"$@"`, not the outer shell.

And actually for maximum pedantry `echo` isn't completely safe, either. If you try to print a string like `-n` it may not be printed literally, but instead interpreted as an option. The safest option of all is to use `printf`:

```
sh -c 'printf "%s\n" "$*"' sh "$@"
```

Comment: @JohnKugelman Why does the `${@[*]}` does not work with the `@` variable ?

Comment: You could think of `$*` and `$@` as ways to access the *unnamed* array of command-line arguments. `${@[*]}` doesn't work because the array's name isn't `@`. I could see an argument for `${[@]}` and `${[*]}`, perhaps, where the name is omitted.

Comment: `sh -c 'echo "$@"' sh "$@"` could have been written `sh -c 'echo "$@"' $0 "$@"`, right ?

Comment: It could, yes. You can pass anything there. Some people pass `--`. Since you're explicitly calling `sh -c`, it makes sense to me to pass `sh`.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using `$*` expansion?
I get the following:

```
$ sh -c "echo $*"
--no-resume-playback https://www.facebook.com/TBN/videos/1580372468665943/
```

Does that suit your needs?